# Odoo many2many checkboxes domain not working

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-15

I have these models

The model event.booth always has a halle_id
The model order.wizard has an event_booth_id and event_booth_ids

Now, in the view form order.wizard in the many2many checkboxes widget from event_booth_ids I only want to show the records where the halle_id matches with the one from event_booth_id.halle_id

This is my current attempt (order wizard form):

```
<record id="rectanglemaps_create_order_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">rectanglemaps.order.wizard.form</field>
      <field name="model">rectanglemaps.order.wizard</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                ...
                <field name="event_booth_ids" widget="many2many_checkboxes" domain="[('halle_id', '=', event_booth_id.halle_id)]"/>
            </form>
      </field>
</record>
```

As you can see i am trying to achieve this with the domain domain="[('halle_id', '=', self.event_booth_id.halle_id)]"

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error

```
Ungültiges zusammengesetztes Feld in domain="[('halle_id', '=', self.event_booth_id.halle_id)]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states: You can not use dottet fields in the second part of the domain. Instead you should create a related field like this:

```
halle_id = self.Many2one(related='event_booth_id.halle_id')
```

and use it in the domain like this:

```
domain="[('halle_id', '=', halle_id)]"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how can i make halle_id present in wizard form? I get this error "Das Feld 'halle_id' , das in domain of <field name="event_booth_ids"> ([('halle_id', '=', halle_id)]) verwendet wird, muss in der Ansicht vorhanden sein, fehlt jedoch"

Comment: nevermind, solved it

Answer (score 1):

You can't use [dotted field names](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a7f7233e0eae8ee101d745a9813cba930fd03dcb/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py#L2256) in domain and by default, `self` is not available in the [evaluation context](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a7f7233e0eae8ee101d745a9813cba930fd03dcb/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/core/py_utils.js#L256-L281)

You can use a related field:

```
halle_id = fields.Many2one(related='event_booth_id.halle_id')
```

And use it in domain like following:

```
domain="[('halle_id', '=', halle_id)]"
```

*The `halle_id` field must be present in wizard form*

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how can i make halle_id present in wizard form?

I get this error
"Das Feld 'halle_id' , das in domain of <field name="event_booth_ids"> ([('halle_id', '=', halle_id)]) verwendet wird, muss in der Ansicht vorhanden sein, fehlt jedoch"

Comment: nevermind, i solved it

Comment: You just need to add the field description in the wizard form view. Example: `<field name="halle_id" invisible="1"/>`